# Changing Application Link URLS from UAT Server to Production Server in Lists Automatically

Tags: 2007, deployment, links-list

I have two SharePoint 2007 sites, a UAT/Development site (ip.ip.ip.ip) and a Production site (intranet.mycompany.com). Each site contains collections of lists pointing to applications our company uses.

The requirement (desire) is that the UAT SharePoint site links point to only the UAT deployments of the applications hosted at (uat.mycompany.com/ApplicationName) and that the Production SharePoint site links point to only the Production applications at (intranet.mycompany.com/ApplicationName). That way, it would be such that the links to applications are dynamic between the UAT and Production Sites.

How can I create links that will reference the UAT Server applications when in the UAT SharePoint site, but reference the Production Server applications when on the Production SharePoint site?

Comment: so, what's the question?

Answer (score 1):

Use relative URL's in the list.  (i.e. use /Page.html instead of site.com/Page.html).

Comment: I thought of using relative URLs, but the UAT Applications and SharePoint are both on different hosts and different sites: i.e., uat.sharepoint.com and prod.sharepoint.com, and uat.applications.com and prod.applications.com. I want all uat.sharepoint.com links to point to uat.applications.com, and all prod.sharepoint.com links to point to prod.applications.com. Is there a way to accomplish this with relative urls?

Answer (score 0):

One option is a URL Rewrite utility like the [free one from Microsoft](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) to create a map of URLs per server and then use an [Outbound Rule](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/657/creating-outbound-rules-for-url-rewrite-module/) to rewrite any links it finds in the html before it is sent to the browser.  This would work but is a fair amount of manual work to keep the list up to date.

There is also [a tool from Helicon](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/) that supposedly can do this as well but I have only used the Helicon tool for managing incoming links

Comment: Thank you for the links, I will give this a try. I don't have as much control over the environment beyond the SharePoint server and I cannot trust the users to keep yet another tool up to date after I leave.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a kind of utility to go through all pages on production , and edit the web part content vias web part manager on the page.

For list content you can write your code using html agility Pack ( http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)